# How to use both Firebase Cloud Messaging and Firebase Auth in Xamarin?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I 'm developing a Xamarin Android native app and I have a problem when I try to use both FCM and Firebase-Authentication.

I first added FCM packages to my app (last version v71.1740), I use FirebaseMessagingService and google-services.json and it works perfectly, OnNewToken method is fired on each new install.

Then I added Firebase-Authentication Nuget packages (v71.16) without modifying anything in my code. I uninstall the app and restart, but I never get any push token.

If I remove Auth packages, OnNewToken method is fired.

Is there anything to do to init Firebase with both modules or is it a Xamarin bug ?
Thanks

Comment: I'm reasonably new to this myself but did you update your google-services Json / PList when you enabled the auth feature? I had a similar problem when I combined services and had to download a new config as some keys had been added.

Comment: Yes I did, but no success. I also tried to create a new blank project which retrieve a push token. It's working fine, but if I add Firebase-Authentication packages: same problem, no token at all. It seems to be a reel bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

in my project i realized that OnNewToken breakpoint not fire, but the token is update normally. I know this because the LOG show me. That's my code:

```
namespace MyApp
{
   [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "Firebase";

        public override void OnNewToken(string token)
        {
            base.OnNewToken(token);

            Log.Debug(TAG, "Update Token: " + token);

            Preferences.Set("TokenFirebase", token);            
        }

        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```